# How to write an update which uses conditional and where

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a function which is called after a trigger is fired:

```
UPDATE scores
                SET points = IF (NEW.success = TRUE, points + 5, points)
                    WHERE match_id = (SELECT match_id FROM player_instance WHERE id = NEW.kicker_id ) AND 
                    team_id = (SELECT team_id FROM player_instance WHERE id = NEW.kicker_id);
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function if(boolean, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 2:                SET  points = IF (NEW.success = TRUE, points ...
                                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type  casts.
QUERY:  UPDATE scores
                SET  points = IF (NEW.success = TRUE, points + 3, points)
                    WHERE match_id = (SELECT match_id FROM player_instance WHERE id =      NEW.kicker_id ) AND 
                      team_id = (SELECT team_id FROM player_instance WHERE id = NEW.kicker_id)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_kicks() line 3 at SQL statement
```

I'm guessing this is because there is no similar 'if' function (this code being copied from a mysql script).

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` is not available in standard SQL and not needed either (that's a MySQL oddity), use [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) instead - as @Houari provided already.

However, executing the `UPDATE` unconditionally means **lots of useless updates**, all writing a new row version for the full price even if nothing changes. Also, two subselects are needlessly expensive.
It should really be:

```
UPDATE scores s
SET    points = points + 5
FROM   player_instance pi
WHERE  pi.id = NEW.kicker_id
AND    s.match_id = pi.match_id 
AND    s.team_id  = pi.team_id 
AND    NEW.success;
```

This way, the `UPDATE` doesn't touch any rows if conditions are not met. Much cheaper.
[Details for UPDATE in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)

Comment: Ok thanks but what does USING do? I can't find it in the manual.

Comment: Sorry but that link contains no example of the 'USING' keyword.

Comment: @user3083672: Oh. Sorry, my bad. Must be `FROM`, not `USING` (which does the same in `DELETE` commands).

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for can be achieve using [CASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) statement:

```
UPDATE scores
                SET points = case when NEW.success is TRUE then points + 5 else points end 
                    WHERE match_id = (SELECT match_id FROM player_instance WHERE id = NEW.kicker_id ) AND 
                    team_id = (SELECT team_id FROM player_instance WHERE id = NEW.kicker_id);
```